# Matplotlib with boxplot cannot set aspect as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I do this with my matplotlib 1.1.1, I have an unexpected result. Is this a bug?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
axs = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
data=[[range(i)] for i in range(10,13)]
p = axs.boxplot(data)
```

Obviously, the aspect is not `equal`, while the `get_aspect()` method still shows `equal`.

Comment: What did you expect? The aspect ratio is exactly equal in as far as the scaling of the x-axis and the y-axis are equal (meaning that a length measured in x-direction is the same as the length measured in y-direction). What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi David, sorry that's it's my stupid misunderstanding... I thought it was the external look of both axes. Thanks a lot for correcting!

Comment: @ShawnWang, you should post your solution as an answer so that you can accept it...

Comment: @ShawnWang Glad your problem is solved! Typically we don't change our posts to "SOLVED" (as other forums do). It might be useful to read up on the FAQ for this site.

Comment: @Hooked Thank you for pointing this out! I will read the FAQ. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment by @DavidZwicker:

> The aspect ratio is exactly equal in as far as the scaling of the x-axis and the y-axis are equal (meaning that a length measured in x-direction is the same as the length measured in y-direction).

**Note**: This answer is a community wiki so the question can be marked solved. All credit goes to the author.